# Using global styles when you already use css modules in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I use css modules in my react app but i have a package that uses the default css styling method. The issue is when i import css styles that way, it does not work because i use css modules

Comment: How do you import the stylesheet file?
If you do something like:  import styles from './App.css';
Change it to  import from './App.css';

Comment: `create-react-app` provides support for css modules if you add `.modules` to the file name, If you want global styling, creating a normal CSS file `App.css` and importing it like ` import "./App.css" ` , this should work

Comment: tried both, still didn't work